# RichTextBox text is disappearing in VisualBrush after detaching from control on screen

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, visualbrush

I have a thumbnail preview which is done through VisualBrush. Preview is of an ItemsControl which contains along other elements RichTextBox.

```
var preview = new VisualBrush(itemsControl, ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
                    Viewbox = Rect(controlSize),
                    Stretch = Stretch.Uniform);
```

When ItemsControl is a part of the Application visual tree everything the preview and the controls themselves display just fine, but when I remove ItemsControl from the Application visual tree (e.g. canvas.Remove(itemsControl)) RichTextBox controls become invisible in the preview (VisualBrush) while all other controls are displaying as usual.

```
public void SetActiveControl(ItemsControl newItemsControl) {
    canvas.Children.Remove(currentItemsControl);
    canvas.Children.Add(newItemsControl);
    currentItemsControl = newItemsControl;
}
```

I compared properties of RichTextBox before and after its beeing detached from Application visual tree. The difference is in the properties IsLoaded (before TRUE, after FALSE) and IsVisible (before TRUE, after FALSE). But other elements (e.g. Path) have the same differences and still display in preview correctly.

I can't grasp how doing canvas.Remove(itemsControl) hides RichTextBox but keeps other controls! Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Visual brush cannot be frozen. So you can create ImageBrush from VisualBrush before detaching your control from visual tree. Here is an example how to do that: [“Freeze” that VisualBrush](http://marktinderholt.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/freeze-that-visualbrush/).